# Stop PHP code executing after it's ran vue form

Tags: php, forms, vue.js, curl

I have the following vue form

```
<FlashMessage message="Message sent!" :show="showMsg" />

<form @submit.prevent.stop="onSubmit" ref="ticketForm">
  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="name">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Full name</span>
      <input
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        placeholder="Sherlock Holmes"
        v-model="formData.name"
        required
        id="name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="email">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Email address</span>
      <input
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        placeholder="sherlock@bakerstreet.com"
        v-model="formData.email"
        required
        id="email"
        name="email"
        type="email"
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="department">
      <span class="text-gray-700">Department</span>
      <select
        class="form-select mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        name="deptid"
        v-model="formData.deptid"
      >
        <option value="1">General Support</option>
        <option value="5">General Support</option>
        <option value="2">Hosting Support</option>
        <option value="3">Domain Support</option>
        <option value="4">Game Support</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="message">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Message</span>
      <textarea
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none h-56 resize-none"
        placeholder="Enter your message here"
        v-model="formData.message"
        name="message"
        id="message"
        cols="30"
        rows="10"
        required
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="flex mt-6">
    <label class="flex items-center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" />
      <span class="ml-2">
        I agree to the
        <a href="#" class="underline">privacy policy</a>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="flex mt-6">
    <label class="flex items-center">
      <button
        type="submit"
        name="ticketSubmit"
        value="Submit"
        class="flex items-center py-3 px-6 border rounded bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 font-medium text-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane mr-4"></i>
        Send
      </button>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I have the following script

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import FlashMessage from "../components/FlashMessage";
import FeaturesWGrid from "../components/FeaturesWGrid";
import Grid from "../components/Grid";
import GridItem from "../components/GridItem";

export default {
  name: "Contact",
  components: {
    FlashMessage,
    FeaturesWGrid,
    Grid,
    GridItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMsg: false,
      formData: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        deptid: "1",
        message: ""
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: async function() {
      this.showMsg = true;
      await axios.post("/backend/contact.php", this.formData);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showMsg = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This shows a submit message, but when I submit it hits the PHP file and keeps loading until it times out. How do I stop the file from loading once all the code has been run whilst staying on the same page?

For some more context here is the PHP file

```
<?php
    $whmcsUrl = "";
    $api_identifier = "";
    $api_secret = "";
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $deptid = $_POST["deptid"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    // Build post values
    $postfields = array(
        'action' => 'OpenTicket',
        'identifier' => $api_identifier,
        'secret' => $api_secret,
        'deptid' => $deptid,
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        "subject" => "Contact form Inquiry from $name",
        'message' => $message,
        'priority' => 'Medium',
        'useMarkdown' => 'false',
        'responsetype' => 'json',
    );

    // Call the API
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whmcsUrl . 'includes/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode response
    $jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

    // Dump array structure for inspection
    var_dump($jsonData);

    exit;
?>
```

PHP code

```php
<?php
    $whmcsUrl = "";
    $api_identifier = "";
    $api_secret = "";
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $deptid = "";
    $message = "";

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['deptid'])) {
        $deptid = $_POST['deptid'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }

    // Build post values
    $postfields = array(
        'action' => 'OpenTicket',
        'identifier' => $api_identifier,
        'secret' => $api_secret,
        'deptid' => $deptid,
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        "subject" => "Contact form Inquiry from $name",
        'message' => $message,
        'priority' => 'Medium',
        'useMarkdown' => 'false',
        'responsetype' => 'json',
    );

    // Call the API
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whmcsUrl . 'includes/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode response
    $jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

    // Dump array structure for inspection
    var_dump($jsonData);
    var_dump($_POST)
?>
```

So once this code gets ran, how do I stop it from loading so it still sends the data but doesn't sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action with and send the data to PHP from the `onSubmit` method

```
<form @submit.prevent.stop="onSubmit" ref="ticketForm">
```

> UPDATES

Initialise the variables required for binding your inputs

```
data:()=>{
  return {
    formData:{
      name:null,
      // your other models
    }
  }
}
```

Use `v-model` to bind the input fields with `data`

```
<form @submit.prevent.stop="onSubmit" ref="ticketForm">
  <input type="text" v-model="formData.name"> // this will bind the typing value to formData.name
</form>
```

Use `axios` to send the data to your `PHP` file from the method `onSubmit`

```
onSubmit: async function(){
  this.showMsg = true;
  await axios.post("/backend/contact.php",this.formData);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showMsg = false;
  }, 3000);
}
```

The `async` and `await` keywords are optional. You can remove if not required.

Comment: How do I go about sending the data? I'll update the question with the PHP code

Comment: It is better to use AJAX to submit the form data to the backend.

Comment: Could you provide an example, because WHMCS it's a CURL/PHP API

Comment: I've tried it for but for this API I have to use CURL for there external API so if you could provide an example using axios that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the sample code. You can use the PHP code same as now. Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: OK so I've setup the models and the function, when I submit the form I get the pop up but no tickets are being generated so I don't think the PHP code is being ran. I'll update the question

Comment: Have you tried printing the $_POST request data? Please var_dump($_POST) and check if all the data are coming.

Comment: I get `[05-Apr-2020 15:06:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name` this is for all fields, email, message, deptid etc

Comment: Please try printing all the data from `$_POST`.

Comment: I've added the PHP code to the question, I'm tried running the form again I get ```array(2) { ["result"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(51) "Name and email address are required if not a client" } array(0) { }```

Comment: The form works if I do ```<form action="/backend/contact.php" method="POST">``` but if I do the ```@submit.prevent.stop="onSubmit"``` the form doesn't work @Rijosh